# How to display a .xls (excel file) stored in res/raw ,android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-resources

I have a .xls stored in res/raw directory. All I need is to display the excel file when the user clicks a button (within the same app, or using third party app doesn't matter. Which ever is easy will do).

Comment: There is no requirement for the user to have an app installed that knows how to render Excel spreadsheets, and Android has no built-in ability to render Excel spreadsheets. Perhaps you should be choosing a different file format, such as HTML, where you will have more options.

Comment: @CommonsWare , ok if its a HTML file or a an .png file, how can I display that file, that is stored in res/raw folder...? Again not necessarily on the same app, any third party app will do... I kind of need to do this some how :(

Comment: Use ACTION_VIEW to let the user choose a suitable viewer.

Comment: Copy the resource to a file, then use `FileProvider` to create a `Uri` that you can use with `ACTION_VIEW`.